# MC 2.0.7 Rest API 400 Bad request

Tags: magento2

I'm getting following response in Magento Restfull API call, with the message I'm not able to identify what is the issue.
Without understanding the error origin we can't fix it. Please help me track down the issue.

Getting issue in all APIs before it were working, I just cleared cache and redeployed the static contents.

> {{basePath}}/rest/V1/customers/me

```
 {
      "message": "Invalid Document \nElement 'resources': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.\nLine: 14\n",
      "trace": "#0 /Users/me/Documents/MAMP/project/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(127): Magento\\Framework\\Config\\Reader\\Filesystem->_readFiles(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Config\\FileIterator))\n#1 /Users/me/Documents/MAMP/project/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/Config.php(67): Magento\\Framework\\Config\\Reader\\Filesystem->read()\n#2 /Users/me/Documents/MAMP/project/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/Rest/Config.php(105): Magento\\Webapi\\Model\\Config->getServices()\n#3 /Users/me/Documents/MAMP/project/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/Router.php(41): Magento\\Webapi\\Model\\Rest\\Config->getRestRoutes(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\Rest\\Request\\Proxy))\n#4 /Users/me/Documents/MAMP/project/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Router/Proxy.php(95): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Router->match(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\Rest\\Request\\Proxy))\n#5 /Users/me/Documents/MAMP/project/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(187): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Router\\Proxy->match(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\Rest\\Request\\Proxy))\n#6 /Users/me/Documents/MAMP/project/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(200): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->getCurrentRoute()\n#7 /Users/me/Documents/MAMP/project/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(286): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->checkPermissions()\n#8 /Users/me/Documents/MAMP/project/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(255): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->validateRequest()\n#9 /Users/me/Documents/MAMP/project/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(160): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->processApiRequest()\n#10 /Users/me/Documents/MAMP/project/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#11 /Users/me/Documents/MAMP/project/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#12 /Users/me/Documents/MAMP/project/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#13 /Users/me/Documents/MAMP/project/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http))\n#14 {main}"
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling by code ? have you tried with post man ?

Comment: @ManthanDave call with Postman and other rest client

Comment: First try to get admin token , you are getting or not